# Is it OK to use multiple inheritance with Django abstract models?

Tags: django, django-models

I have three different abstract model base classes . . . I'd like to use them in multiple inheritance, sort of like Mixins.  Any problems with this?

E.g.,

```
class TaggableBase(models.Model):

. . .

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class TimeStampedBase(models.Model):

. . .

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class OrganizationalBase(models.Model):

. . .

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class MyTimeStampedTaggableOrganizationalModel(OrganizationalBase, TimeStampedBase, TaggableBase):

. . .
```

Comment: thanks for the comment answer :) Make it an answer and I'll vote it up, but either way, looks like I'll try it out and keep my eyes out for any issues.  Seems the biggest potential issue would be with overriding the same method in two inherited classes and understanding how python deals with super and multiple inheritance (which I believe I do).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like for what you're trying to do, [mixins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) really are the best fit.  A simple google search will find lots of articles on implementing mixins in python, such as [this one](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4540).  I'm not sure multiple inheritance is the best way to go about doing it, so you might want to explore all the other options.  What else have you thought about?

Comment: For anyone looking at this, I found this blog post to be helpful.  Whether you call it a mixin or multiple inheritance it ends up with the same successful effect: http://www.djangocurrent.com/2011/05/django-aspect-oriented-models.html

Comment: How are mixins different than multiple inheritence? They seem to be the same thing with different names.

Comment: @varikin You might want to take a look at this article: http://www.oreillynet.com/ruby/blog/2007/01/digging_deep_mixing_it_up_or_i_1.html

Comment: Just a note, my code above works fine, and this is generally how I implement "mixins" for models, so I don't take Nick's suggestion to mean I should do things any differently. In fact, I'm not sure if it would work if you didn't have the abstract=True in each of the Meta classes and didn't have each mixin inherit from models.Model.  I use Multiple Inheritance i.e. mixins, a lot in django and find it a very useful way in both class-based views and models to keep things DRY.  Just make sure you understand the implications and that the ordering of your parent classes matters, a lot.

Comment: As has been mentioned elsewhere, mixins don't work if you have Django model fields in your mixin, so this doesn't quite answer the question.

Answer (score 27):

If you use *any **fields** at all* in your class, inherit from `models.Model`.

Otherwise Django will ignore those fields (the attributes will still be there in Python, but no fields will be created in the DB). Set `abstract = True` to get "mixin" like behavior (i.e. no DB tables will be created for the mixins but for the models using those mixins).

If you don't use any fields, you can just inherit from `object`, to keep things plain and simple.

Comment: Since the superclasses inherit from `models.Model`, the subclass should inherit from it too and thus not get ignored. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance. 
This documentation also shows how to use the abstract field to avoid creating a table as you said: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

Comment: I tried this approach but I'm getting `Cannot create a consistent method resolution order (MRO) for bases Model, MyBaseModel`. Has anybody managed to make this work?

Comment: Relevant reading: [Abstract models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes). [Django models support multiple inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#multiple-inheritance).

Answer (score 15):

I do this all the time with my classes and model classes. It's one of the best things in Python, in my opinion.